# Invalid Identifier for type paramters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute what should be a simple query to get a distance column containing the distance from one SDO_GEOMETRY to another.

My code is as below

```
DECLARE query VARCHAR(4000); L_LATITUDE number; L_LONGITUDE number;

BEGIN 
IF :P7_USER_POSTCODE IS NOT NULL THEN
    brian.GEOCODE_GM_JSON (:P7_USER_POSTCODE, L_LATITUDE, L_LONGITUDE);
END IF;


query :=     'SELECT 
                     S.SPOT_ID,
                     dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
                     IND.SPOT_NAME,
                     IND.SPOT_DESCRIPTION,
                     SPOT.POSTCODE
             FROM SPOT_IMAGES S
             INNER JOIN SURFSPOTINDEX IND ON IND.SPOT_ID = S.SPOT_ID
             INNER JOIN SPOT_LOCATION SPOT ON SPOT.SPOT_ID = IND.SPOT_ID';

IF :P7_SEARCH IS NULL AND :P7_USER_POSTCODE IS NULL THEN
    return query;


ELSIF :P7_SEARCH IS NOT null  AND :P7_USER_POSTCODE IS NULL THEN

    query := query || ' ' ||
          'WHERE CONTAINS(IND.SPOT_DESCRIPTION, :P7_SEARCH, 123) > 0
           OR UPPER(IND.SPOT_NAME) LIKE UPPER(''%'' || :P7_SEARCH || ''%'')
            ';

            RETURN query;


ELSIF :P7_SEARCH IS null  AND :P7_USER_POSTCODE IS NOT NULL THEN


        query :=     'SELECT 
                     S.SPOT_ID,
                     dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
                     IND.SPOT_NAME,
                     IND.SPOT_DESCRIPTION,
                     SPOT.POSTCODE,
                     ASDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(SPOT.LOCATION,
                                          SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,
                                          4326,
                                          SDO_POINT_TYPE(L_LONGITUDE, L_LATITUDE, null),
                                          null,
                                          null)
                     ,0.005, ''unit=mile'')   as DISTANCE
             FROM SPOT_IMAGES S
             INNER JOIN SURFSPOTINDEX IND ON IND.SPOT_ID = S.SPOT_ID
             INNER JOIN SPOT_LOCATION SPOT ON SPOT.SPOT_ID = IND.SPOT_ID
             ORDER BY Distance ASC';

          RETURN query;

END IF;

END;
```

The final else if is where the error occurs.

I get the error

```
 ORA-00904: "LONGITUDE": invalid identifier
```

I cannot figure out why this is having googled the error code extensively.
The GEOCODE_GM_JSON returns latitude and longitude in the input variables and I have tested this and it is working correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The first two lines are not valid SQL. To use assignment, the code needs to be wrapped in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: I am actually using the code in an APEX application. The parameters are defined at the top using DECLARE at the top of the procedure and assigned using user defined input. However I get the same error there.

Comment: Is the error occurring calling this block, or trying to run the returned query? Is the error actually referring to `LONGITUDE`, or `L_LONGITUDE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the full error stack and the message doesn't quite seem to correspond to your amended code, but it looks like you're embedding the string literals `L_LATITUDE` and `L_LONGITUDE` in the query string you're returning; but those variables don't mean anything to the caller when it tries to run that generated code.

You could concatenate in the actual variable values:

```
                     ASDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(SPOT.LOCATION,
                                          SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,
                                          4326,
                                          SDO_POINT_TYPE('
                                            || L_LONGITUDE ||', '|| L_LATITUDE
                                            ||', null),
                                          null,
                                          null)
                     ,0.005, ''unit=mile'')   as DISTANCE
```

although that means that every query will have to be hard-parsed because of those literal values. Another function that returns the SDO point for the post code, instead of the latitude and longitude, might better if Apex can refer to that bind variable when it executes the query - the query in the previous branch, using `:P7_SEARCH`, implies it can. That would remove the concatenation, removing that hard-parse and reducing potential for SQL injection.

Comment: Same goes for :P7_SEARCH from the first query. I presume OP wants to concatenate values to the query, which is a great way to introduce SQL injection...

Comment: I believe Apex will still bind `:P7_SEARCH` when it executes the generated query. Assuming that branch works, which is implied. The issue here seems to be the translation to latitude/longitude via a procedure, which the query execution can't use directly. If that's right then the injection risk depends on the conversion procedure here? But yes, pointing out the risk of concatenation is always a good idea. I don't know enough about Apex to know if this approach is necessary at all though - sees unlikely...

Comment: This solved my problem as it was simply passing back the parameter string to be executed instead of the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DEFINE` to use external variables. Then use it as `&variable_name` in your query.

```
DEFINE LATITUDE = 50.5261556;
DEFINE LONGITUDE = -5.5261556;


SELECT 
                 S.SPOT_ID,
                 dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
                 IND.SPOT_NAME,
                 IND.SPOT_DESCRIPTION,
                 SPOT.POSTCODE,
                 SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(SPOT.LOCATION,
                                          SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,
                                          4326,
                                          SDO_POINT_TYPE(&LATITUDE, &LONGITUDE, null),
                                          null,
                                          null)
                     ,0.005, 'unit=mile') 
         FROM SPOT_IMAGES S
         INNER JOIN SURFSPOTINDEX IND ON IND.SPOT_ID = S.SPOT_ID
         INNER JOIN SPOT_LOCATION SPOT ON SPOT.SPOT_ID = IND.SPOT_ID;
```

Comment: In the production code the parameters are declared at the top using DECLARE. The code is in an APEX function which returns a query and does not seem to like the DEFINE keyword. Can DECLARED variable not be passed in?

Comment: @Nick If its declared using `DECLARE` then it must be a block. It cannot be a standalone query. Show full code how its in Production. What is answered above will surely work if you are trying to run standalone query using `SQLPLUS`

Comment: I have changed the code in the question to make it clearer what I'm actually trying to do. Thanks